# accessing shockwave player using httpclient

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

i was trying to access a webpage which contains content/type : flash Shock-Wave 
i am fetching the page with GET Method so that i can get responseBodyAsString()
but player is not working .

How to get the flash shock wave working ?